# How to compile two projects that reference each other

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, tsconfig

I am having issues building a project `(@red5/middleware)` that references another project `(@red5/router)` and in return that project references this project `(@red5/middleware)`.

So, when I run the command:

```
rm -rf types && tsc -p .
```

I get an error that says it cannot find the `.d.ts` file(s) because I removed them with `rm`.

> ../router/types/Route.d.ts:4:28 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module '@red5/middleware'. 'C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/vscode/projects/red5/framework/middleware/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/red5__middleware` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@red5/middleware';`

**@red5/router -> route.ts**

```
import { Middleware } from '@red5/middleware';
```

If I remove the `rm -rf types` command, I get errors saying that it cannot overwrite the input file, but I no longer get the above error.

What can I do to get rid of this error and still use `rm -rf types` in my command?

**middleware/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "declarationDir": "types"
  },
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "types"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, was basically just a modification of the `tsconfig.json` file.

Two items are needed:

1. `compilerOptions.baseUrl` - Base directory to resolve non-relative module names.
2. `compilerOptions.paths` - List of path mapping entries for module names to locations relative to the baseUrl.

So, in the `@red5/middleware` module we reference the router like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@red5/router": [ "../router" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the `@red5/router` module we reference the middleware like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@red5/middleware": [ "../middleware" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Everything then resolves to the proper locations.

Answer (score 0):

Are these projects that you are building, or are currently being built? If so, this sounds like an issue with the dependency pattern you're using.

However, regardless - in order to acheive this, you will need to update one module at a time.

Using the previous version of the older module, you should be able to use that final output as your dependency for the current version of the new module.

Then, once you have those items updated - go ahead and modify the other solution.

You will have to work on one solution and then the other - if you implement changes in both, you will break the dependency and won't be able to compile either of them.

Comment: Hmm... Looks like I will need to change the dependency pattern somehow... I was hoping I didn't have to do this, as I would like each to be and stay module...

Comment: Looks like I can add the option `"skipLibCheck": true` to my `tsconfig.json`